# How can I tell if my battery is damaged physically?

Tags: batteries, damage

I have boughten a rechargeable battery and a charger a few months ago and when I received it, I briefly hooked it up to a multimeter and shoved it in the back of a drawer to use on another project that I was planning to do a couple days later, but it didn't work out, and I kinda forgot about it.

Fast forward a few months. Today, I checked it again, and then I wanted to see if it would fit inside a small space with a wire. It fit perfectly without the wire, but I had to force it a little to get it into the case. When I pulled it out, I noticed that there were some weird "bumps" running along the long way of the battery, but not perfectly straight. I never looked it *that* closely, but I would assume I would notice it.

That isn't my question. I don't know if it was manufactured that way, it was damaged during shipping, or if I did it. It is a little late to contact the seller, my fault, of course. **Is this just a cosmetic flaw that I don't have to worry about? (I found a different use for the battery, so it's not going to be crammed in there anymore.) Should I buy a new one? Test it?** It's kinda weird, and it seems cosmetic (no leaks... yet), but I am reluctant to charge it or use it unless I know it's okay and safe.

---

**Photos:**

[image: Battery 1]

[image: Battery 2]

[image: Battery 3]

I don't mind replacing them if necessary, but I want to get this done without waiting for a part to come if I can.

They are AAs; "GTL Li-ion 14500 1200mAh 3.7v."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the best way to check if a battery is damaged is to hook it up to a multimeter and check the output voltage (if it's fully charged).  It should be safe to charge and test unless it is leaking fluid.  It's always a good idea to keep an eye on them while they are charging, especially if you think they may be damaged.

Comment: With the multimeter is it checking for meeting the voltage? I hooked up mine and it was around 3.81v for one and 3.87v for the second; even though it is a 3.7v battery. Is this an indication of a problem, or is it just charged fully and goes a little over the voltage like car batteries do?

Comment: If its a lithium (LiOn/LiPo) battery, the voltage can go up to 4.2v when fully charged - so it should be OK. The bumps may just be wrinkles in the covering (plastic), or it may be a leakage.

Comment: I think it's just a wrinkle in or under the casing, where the casing is joined together. 3.8V is normal.

Comment: @RonJ. That's probably it. It would be pretty hard to destroy the metal by shoving it in with a wire into *plastic*. The plastic would most likely snap first. I decided to lightly press all around the battery and it seemed like it did get better: I think it was mostly air, although I did get about a tablespoon or two of liquid that is starting to smoke.... must have done something right!!! **:P**

Answer (score 2):

There is no scale or marking ls in your picture.  But that looks like an 18650 Lithium Ion battery.

If so, is it a protected cell?

Protected batteries have a tiny PCB mounted between the negative flat plate and the actual negative terminal of the cell.  They also have a small wire or metal strip that runs up the side.  I think that is what you are feeling.

The protection circuit cuts power to the battery if it goes under or over a safe voltage or goes over a safe current.  This is to (hopefully) prevent it from exploding if you were to short it out.

Comment: I don't remember the numbers, but on the side, it says, "GTL Li-ion 14500 1200mAh 3.7v" The protected cell: the + tip is covered by white and then the blue shrink wrap type thing and only the part sticking up is exposed. I'll post pics. Also, it doesn't seem like a machined thing; it goes kinda crooked and it seems almost like a crack, however, it isn't leaking or anything.